# How to save UTF-16 (Little Endian) and String value inside a file in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to save the value inside the Edit Box and the UTF-16 (Little Endian) value in a file.

I will give a simple example to better understand my question:

```
Edit Box Value => 'Good';
Hex value = FFFEFF15410042004300
which is equivalent to UTF-16 (Little Endian) => ᗿABC
```

Now I want the value of `Good` and `ᗿABC` to be saved in a file, so that if we open the saved file with Notepad, it will display the value: `ᗿABCGood` and if we open it with a Hex Editor, it will display the value: `FFFEFF1541004200430047006F006F006400`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hex is simply the raw bytes of the UTF-16 (Little Endian) encoded form of the strings.

Delphi versions prior to 2009 (like Delphi 7) have very limited support for Unicode, but you can simply assign your strings to `WideString` (Delphi's wrapper for a UTF-16LE COM string) and then write the raw bytes of its characters to the file, prepended with a UTF-16LE BOM, eg:

```pascal
uses
  Classes;

const
  BOM: WideChar = WideChar($FEFF);
var
  W: WideString;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  W := 'ᗿABC';
  FS := TFileStream.Create('text.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    FS.WriteBuffer(BOM, Sizeof(BOM));
    FS.WriteBuffer(PWideChar(W)^, Length(W) * Sizeof(WideChar));
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Since 2009, Delphi has much more support for UTF-16 strings, via `UnicodeString`, `TEncoding.(BigEndian)Unicode`, etc. For example:

```pascal
uses
  System.IOUtils;

begin
  TFile.WriteAllText('text.txt', 'ᗿABC', TEncoding.Unicode);
end;
```