# Save Hex value or UTF-16 [LE] inside a file in Delphi 7 [Error in using these codes]

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Continuing from my previous question: [How to save UTF-16 (Little Endian) and String value inside a file in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150675/)

When I use the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76152582/65863):

```pascal
uses
  Classes;
    
const
  BOM: WideChar = $FEFF;
var
  W: WideString;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  W := 'ᗿABC';
  FS := TFileStream.Create('text.txt', fmCreate);
  try
    FS.WriteBuffer(BOM, Sizeof(BOM));
    FS.WriteBuffer(PWideChar(W)^, Length(W) * Sizeof(WideChar));
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have these problems:

1. when I used this: `W := 'ᗿABC';` my IDE showed `W := '?ABC';` Can I fix this problem? Because [?] is not my goal
2. When running the code, I get the error in the image:

[image]

Comment: Please add the procedure / function that saves the content of your edit boxes to the file.

Comment: [You've asked this before and it was answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150675/how-to-save-utf-16-little-endian-and-string-value-inside-a-file-in-delphi-7).

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Yes Of course i used of these codes for save file:
var
  MyText: TStringlist;
begin
  MyText:= TStringlist.create;
  try
    MyText.Add('line 1');
    MyText.Add('line 2');
    MyText.SaveToFile('c:\folder\filename.txt');
  finally
    MyText.Free
  end; {try}

Comment: and use of these codes for HEX convert:

function String2Hex(const Buffer: AnsiString): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  BinToHex(PAnsiChar(Buffer), PChar(Result), Length(Buffer));
end;

function Hex2String(const Buffer: string): AnsiString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) div 2);
  HexToBin(PChar(Buffer), PAnsiChar(Result), Length(Result));
end;

var
  hex: string;
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  hex := String2Hex('stackoverflow');
  ShowMessage(hex); // shows 'hex'
  str := Hex2String(hex);
  ShowMessage(str); // shows 'stackoverflow'
end;

Comment: @AmigoJack, No, unfortunately, I had asked the wrong question, that's why I didn't get the right answer!

Comment: @AdamLuper I already covered this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150675/). You are not asking a new question, you are just rephrasing the last question. The same solution I gave you earlier still applies here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thank you, but I get the following error when running the code:
[Error] Unit1.pas(28): Incompatible types: 'WideChar' and 'Integer'

Comment: @AdamLuper then you are not using the code correctly. If you had a problem with the code you were given earlier, you should have commented on it back then. Now, nothing in this new question actually relates to this new problem you are having. So please, [edit] this question to remove all of the irrelevant info, and instead show the actual code you are having trouble with now, and the error message, and indicate where in the code the error is occurring.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm sorry, I thought this question was different from the previous one, that's why I asked a new question, should I continue with the same question or edit the previous question?

Comment: @AdamLuper the previous question has already been answered and closed. This new question has nothing to do with the error message you are getting now. So either close this question and post a new one just about the error. Or else edit this question accordingly.  As it stands right now, this new question is not answerable in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code editor in Delphi 7 does not support Unicode characters very well, if at all. You *really* should stop using a 25-year-old compiler and upgrade.

   In any case, try this instead:

   ```
   W := #$15FF'ABC';
   ```

   Or, you may have to resort to something more like this:

   ```
   W := WideChar($15FF) + WideString('ABC');
   ```
2. Try type-casting the integer value to `WideChar`:

   ```
   const
     BOM: WideChar = WideChar($FEFF);
   ```

   Otherwise, use `Word` instead of `WideChar`:

   ```
   const
     BOM: Word = $FEFF;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your many tips.
What version of Delphi do you recommend that is most compatible with Delphi 7 codes and does not require learning a new language? (Because I have many sources that are useful in Delphi 7 language!)

Comment: I got the full answer to my question, just to get more information, I will ask some very beginner questions and if you don't like it, don't answer:

const
   BOM: WideChar = WideChar($FEFF);

What exactly does this value ($FEFF) do? Can't get inside
  W := WideChar($15FF) + WideString('ABC');
put directly?

Values in WideChar ($15FF) are stored in reverse in the file?

or values
($15FF)
FF after 15 will not be in
const
   BOM: WideChar = WideChar($FEFF);
put directly?

I want to know exactly what the use of each one is and if there is no problem if each one is edited?

Comment: instead of the number 15 in the following code:
W := WideChar($15FF) + WideString('ABC');

How can I set a variable so that the user's age is received from the edit box and is placed instead of the value 15?

Comment: @AdamLuper you definitely need to use a Unicode compatible Delphi version, that is Delphi 2009 and newer! Then you wouldn't have to fiddle around with BOM as hex codes etc.!

Comment: @DelphiCoder, Thank you, you are right, will all the codes used in Delphi 7 change and become unusable to switch to the new Delphi?
Is it possible to use the variable in W := WideChar($15FF) instead of the number 15?

Comment: @AdamLuper `$FEFF` is the UTF-16 [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which lets readers know the text's encoding and endian. Code written in pre-2009 Delphi will port to post-2009 Delphi with little-to-no changes, except when dealing with code that assumed `Sizeof(Char)=1`, or stored binary data in `string`, etc. See [Unicode in RAD Studio](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio) and Embarcadero's [Migration and Upgrade Center](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/migration-upgrade-center#unicode) for more details.

Comment: @AdamLuper based on your descriptions,  you do not appear to be dealing with a pure text-only file, but rather a mix of text and binary data. You probably should NOT be trying to encode the Age and Score values as Unicode characters to begin with. For instance, write a `$FF` byte first, followed by the Age value as its own separate byte. Repeat for Score

Comment: @RemyLebeau,
I used these codes:


const
  BOM: WideChar = WideChar($FEFF);
var
  W1: WideString;
  FS: TFileStream;
  Num_value: string;
begin
Num_value := Hex2String(IntToStr(Edit1.GetTextLen));
W1 := WideChar($FF) + Num_value;


output file in Hex Editor:
FFFE3F002100 -> is not true

But if i used static 21 number (WideChar($21FF)), output file in Hex editor is :
FFFEFF21  -> this is true

Which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AdamLuper I still think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what Unicode is and what your file data is actually meant to represent (you never explained why the file needs to look the way you want), and so you are approaching your issue from the wrong direction to begin with. But, to answer your specific question, to let the user enter `21` and write it out as a `WideString` as `WideChar($21FF)` (bytes `FF 21`), you would need something more like this instead: `Num_value := WideChar(((StrToInt('$'+Edit1.Text) and $FF) shl 8) or $FF)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, This code was awesome!
Num_value := WideChar(((StrToInt('$'+Edit1.Text) and $FF) shl 8) or $FF)

Now how can I save this number as Hex!
That is, for example, the value inside Edit1.Text should be converted to Hex, for example, if the number 21 is inside Edit1.Text, it should be converted to Hex 15.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I received the best, most complete and most professional answers from you.
I am working on a series of simple text files that I use this method to prevent the manipulation of text values so that normal people cannot easily change the text values and any change will make the text file unreadable and usable. !
And I use the combination of text and Hex with a series of other values!

Comment: @AdamLuper if the user is meant to enter a decimal number instead of a hex number, then simply drop the `'$' ` when calling `StrToInt()`, eg: `Num_value := WideChar(((StrToInt(Edit1.Text) and $FF) shl 8) or $FF)`

Answer (score 1):

Using Delphi 7 *kind of* works with Unicode in `WideString`s, but it is not consistent:

```pascal
var
  RegExprWLineSeparators: WideString;
begin
  // In the following line the literal ends up producing ASCII question marks for the 5th and 6th character.
  RegExprWLineSeparators:= #$d#$a#$b#$c+ WideChar($2028)+ WideChar($2029)+ #$85;

  // But assigning characters individually will make both correct - so first do the one above
  // (or provide anything, because you want to reassign it anyway) and later make it per character.
  RegExprWLineSeparators[5]:= WideChar($2028);
  RegExprWLineSeparators[6]:= WideChar($2029);
```

A few characters aren't even assignable this way (neither via text literal, nor via ordinal literal), so you use a different approach to test against these:

```pascal
var
  sText: Widestring;
begin
  sText:= <something>;

  // Checking if the first character is a UTF-16 BE or LE BOM
  case Word(sText[1]) of
    $FEFF,
    $FFFE: Delete( sText, 1, 1 );  // Remove such a character
  end;
```

Thumb of rules are:

- use `Word`s and cast them to `WideChar` when using text literals
- use `Word` over `WideChar` when comparing/checking
- [noncharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#General_Category_property) (like U+FFFE and U+FFFF) are usually unassignable

Using Delphi 7 for Unicode as a beginner should be avoided - do this when you're confident with Unicode, [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and Pascal in general. I started this since Windows 2000 on Delphi 5 and later continued with Delphi 7, having experiences like these in different occasions (regular expressions, amongst others).

As an alternative to a dated Delphi version you could try the free [Lazarus IDE](https://www.lazarus-ide.org) for [FPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal) - it uses UTF-8 as an approach to Unicode and should treat/support text literals in code much better. The IDE even looks like the robust Delphi 7 one.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information you provided.
What version of Delphi do you recommend to replace Delphi 7 that has the least problems with Delphi 7 code? I don't just mean changing the IDE.

Comment: None - I'd recommend Lazarus. Also take the [tour] - you can upvote answers and/or comments if you're thankful.

Comment: I Know but (You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote) i can't cast vote!